# Perl vivification question while dereferencing undefined array reference

Tags: perl, autovivification

I'm having tough time in understanding why the following works:

```
my $array_reference;
foreach $element (@{$array_reference}) {
# some code
}
```

while the following does not work

```
my $array_reference;
if (scalar (@{$array_reference}) {
    # some code here
}
```

I understand that perl brings to life (auto-vivifies) undefined reference. But I am still confused as in why the latter code segment throws FATAL.

Comment: Good question.  Note that the first sequence actually auto-vivifies the reference.  So your script will work if the `if` comes after the `foreach`, but not vice-versa.  I think this is just an obscure (undocumented?) detail of Perl, but I am curious to see the answers.

Comment: nemo - I do not think execution would flow into foreach loop for undefined references. May be I'm missing something

Comment: No, execution does not flow "into" the loop, because the auto-vivified array is empty.  But once you execute the `foreach` on the undefined reference, the reference is no longer undefined...  So you can call `scalar @$reference` on it successfully.

Comment: I'm surprised that the first (foreach) doesn't even warn.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dereferences autovivify in lvalue context (meaning when a modifiable value is expected), and foreach create an lvalue context.

```
>perl -E"$$x = 1;  say $x;"
SCALAR(0x74b024)

>perl -E"++$$x;  say $x;"
SCALAR(0x2eb024)

>perl -E"\$$x;  say $x;"
SCALAR(0x30b024)

>perl -E"sub {}->($$x);  say $x;"
SCALAR(0x27b03c)

>perl -E"for ($$x) {}  say $x;"
SCALAR(0x25b03c)
```

The last two create an lvalue context because they need a value to which to alias `$_[0]` and `$_` (respectively).

Answer (score 7):

Perl has inconsistencies in this area, but in general, code that may modify a structure autovivifies, while code that won't doesn't.  And if it doesn't autovivify, it is trying to dereference an undefined value, which triggers a warning, or, under `use strict "refs"`, an exception.

Comment: But `foreach` does not modify the variable; it just reads it.  Yet it autovivifies...

Comment: @Nemo, foreach does indeed take lvalues (modifiable values): `foreach (@$a) { $_ = uc($_) }`

Comment: @ikegami:  Aha, right, forgot about that.  OK then I guess it is consistent. +1 to both responses.

Answer (score 4):

I think, looking at [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html), that this is expected behaviour:

"*References of the appropriate type can spring into existence if you dereference them in a context that assumes they exist.*"

A similar thing to foreach happens with push() and friends:

```
my $f;
push @$f, 1;
say @$f;
```

Although not with the new, can-just-take-a-reference versions:

```
my $f = [];
push $f, 1;
say @$f;
```

works, while

```
my $f;
push $f, 1;
say @$f;
```

does not, which I think is sensible as push has no idea what you really meant there.

The interesting question is should scalar(@$undef) do the same thing, or should warn, as it eventually returns undef, I think it might as well warn right away.

Comment: "Expected behavior"?  Meaning `foreach` "assumes they exist" but `scalar` does not?  This looks like a seriously under-specified part of the Perl language.  Could either of these examples change their behavior in version N+1?  I  honestly do not know.