# Why does Autovivification occur with keys() and not %{..}?

Tags: perl, hash, key, dereference, autovivification

This is a subtlety I found with `keys()`.

```
$ perl -e 'use warnings; use strict; my $d = { "ab" => 1 }; my @e = keys(%{$d->{cd}});'

$ perl -e 'use warnings; use strict; my $d = { "ab" => 1 }; my %e = %{$d->{cd}};'
Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference at -e line 1.
```

I am most puzzled as to why the first snippet would not give an dereferencing error.  When I use `Data::Dumper`, it becomes clear that in the first snippet, `$d->{cd}`, is autovivified to be `{}`.

Why does `keys` need to autovivify? I tried reading the `perldoc` for it, could not find a satisfying answer. `keys` does not set an alias (`$_`, etc) so there is no need for perl to think `$d->{cd}` needs to be in lvalue context, is there? (I understand if the expression needs to be in lvalue context autovivification happens as explained [here](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2011/04/understand-autovivification).

A relevant [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419618/perl-vivification-question-while-dereferencing-undefined-array-reference).

Comment: https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=118983

Answer (score 4):

Note that keys can indeed be an lvalue (setting the hash's expected number of elements).

But even if keys itself isn't used in an lvalue context, it has a side effect of resetting a hash's iterator.

So it does modify the hash and so gives the dereference an lvalue context, which makes it autovivify.

Answer (score 0):

After some research and asking around, I found that this has to do with the fact that `$d->{cd}` was passed to a subroutine, not the fact that it was `keys`. For instance,

```
% perl -e 'use warnings; use strict; my $d = { "ab" => 1 }; sub foo {}; my @e = foo(%{$d->{cd}});'
```

This will also autovivify; this is because internally perl needs to be able to set an alias to function arguments.

Inside `foo()`, we have an alias set `$_[0] = $d->{cd}` But that means `$d->{cd}` needs to be lvalue-able, since subroutines in perl assume you can do something like `$_[0] = "123";` so the autovivification needs to happen.

Comment: You're right about subroutine arguments being lvalues, but `keys` is an operator, not a subroutine. The argument to `keys` is treated as an lvalue, but this is not the case for all operators. Compare `perl -E'keys %$h; say $h'` to `perl -E'length %$h; say $h'`.